# Refresh table which contain a php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP code, which is in a table tag.It shows a text from database. I want to refresh this table, to load updated text from database in every - let's say - 1 minute without refreshing the whole page. I've found several solutions to reload table without refreshing a page and it seems it can be done with AJAX or JS, but they only refresh it with a specific content or a specific file, however, I can't figure out how to refreshed.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th class="col_small col_center">Employees</th>
      <th class="col_small col_center">% Percentage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $employeeslist=$emp_departmentObj->selectorgall(); 
        foreach($employeeslist as $list)
        { 
          $total=$emp_regObj->selectorgall(); 
          $totalemp=count($total); 
          $deptemp=$emp_regObj->selectemployee($list->id); 
          $totaldeptemp=count($deptemp);  
          $percentage=($totaldeptemp/$totalemp)*100; 
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"><?php echo $list->department ?></a></td>
      <td class="col_center">
        <?php echo $totaldeptemp; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="col_center">
        <?php echo number_format($percentage,1).'%'; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: PHP is server side, it can't be used to "refresh" content on the client, that is Javascript's job. Once PHP is ran, it is done, it can't do anything else.

Comment: Create a function on your PHP then return the data that you need to update, do an ajax call to it and on the success of the call, add the text to your table using JavaScript, jQuery or what you are using on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in document ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() { rebindTable() }, 3000);

function rebindTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:80/data.php",
        success: function(result) {
            var data = result;
            $('#td-1-data').html(data.param1);
            $('#td-2-data').html(data.param2);
        }
    });

}
})
```

this way you can use an setInterval method and re-bind the data in the table using ajax , in this i assume your http://localhost:80/data.php is returning some data which your are binding to the td of the table you have defined